# Calculating Pearson correlation and significance in R

Tags: r, significance, pearson-correlation

I am trying to examine association of two variables i.e., number of publications and publication years. My dataframe looks like this:

```
   Year yr RI1 RI2 RI3 RI4 RI5 RI6 RI7 RI8 RI9 RI10 Total    X
1  2005  1   2   2   3   8   2   7  16  42   1    3    86   NA
2  2006  2   1   2   9   8   1   8  25  40   0    3    97   NA
3  2007  3   9   2  13  10   3   6  32  32   2    2   111   NA
4  2008  4   4   0  12   6   3   5  31  60   1    5   127   NA
5  2009  5  13   5  12   9   5   5  28  55   3    3   138   NA
6  2010  6  13   4  11  10   3   7  33  64   5    1   151   NA
7  2011  7  10  13  10  10   4   3  42  61   4    3   160   NA
8  2012  8  11   6  18  15   6   5  43  64   6    2   176   NA
9  2013  9  22  11  17  12   6   7  50  62   9    5   201 1247
10   NA NA  85  45 105  88  33  53 300 480  31   27  1247   NA
```

I have used `cor()` function as follows but do not get results:

```
year = researchinstitutions$Year
> RI1 = researchinstitutions$RI1
> cor(year,RI1)
[1] NA
```

Any suggestions on how to go around this?

Comment: Try this example, we need to remove NA: `cor(runif(10), c(runif(9), NA), use = "complete.obs")`

Comment: Are you sure you want to check correlation between date that increments annually by 1 vs. research output, would suggest `rank` and `diff` functions to differentiate among institutions

Comment: @Ossan..Yes, i want to check correlation between date vs. research output